# Correct way to implement anonymous authentication for an application?

Tags: android, rest, security

I'm looking for your input in authentication to a rest api related question.

Now Imagine the following scenario:
I have an android app that wants to use resources provided by an public API called MAIN_API (which i have no control over) that has a universal API key. The API key grants access to risky actions such as deleting records.

Now i want to allow the users of the app to have a very limited access to the API resources, but i want them to be able to use the application anonymously ( no credentials of their own).

I figured that the best way to approach this is to have another server that would contain the API-key and would provide the means for the limited access for the MAIN_API (for example PROXY_API would only call simple query endpoints). The actual mobile app would call this API. Call it PROXY_API for the purpose of explanation

Do you think this approach is enough to stop malicious usage of the MAIN_API? Do you think it would be beneficial to generate some sort of application credentials getting an access token from the PROXY_API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provide basic authentication to a web service is quite simple and will depend on the technology stack you are using on the server.

I'd recommend that if you need to both grant users and client applications access to resources to use an authorization mechanism such as OAuth. There are Opensource OAuth server implementations available. Though the OAuth server is a standalone component, securing your resource server to check authorization against the actual OAuth server may depend on your technology stack.

If you are not very knowledgeable about security, and want to control access to your API/Webapp using OAuth, I'd recommend you a service like [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com/),  [Auth0](https://auth0.com) or [3Scale](https://www.3scale.net/). They first two offer free accounts and can help you kick start your product.

Comment: I'm not sure that OAuth is the answer i am looking for. You see the proxy server would contain the API key for the real API and make requests to it. This would add a layer between the API and an anonymous Client app. What i am concerned about is this enough to avoid abuse of the infrastructure. (Given that the proxy server is set up correctly)

Comment: Whoever has access to the proxy can have privileged access to the resources. How are you protecting access to the proxy? I guess you are just moving the problem to another layer.

Comment: Wouldnt it be possible so that the proxy has an endpoint e.g proxyapi.com/simpledata which would validate, adjust and forward the request to endpoint realapi.com/complexdatawithparams and only that. Wouldnt this limit the access of the client app to  proxyapi.com/simpledata since we wouldnt expose the realapi.com outside of the proxy?

Comment: After some tought i think  the OAuth (especially Client Credentials Grant) is the way to go. Cheers @dcerecedo!

Comment: Guess I now understand what you mean. Your proxy should only implement access to the limited use cased scenarios of the remote API and the proxy endpoint should require authenticated access by the user. I'd add it to your app's backend instead of creating a separate software component. Mostly because you need the same user security both for your app and to access the API through the proxy.